# Persistent Rails Webrick server with Vagrant after logging out of box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, webrick

I have a Rails app setup to start on a Vagrant Box. I do:

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
cd /vagrant
rails server &
```

At this point everything is fine - I have the app up and running and all is well. I would like to go back to my dev machine while having the box running so i just logout <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>. At this point, when I try to access the app. I get a `200 OK` response but a blank page. When I do `vagrant ssh` and get the local page, I get the same result: `200 OK` 0-byte response.

It seems that logging out is deactivating the Webrick server, while also not killing it (the process is working and can be killed).

I would like to stress that the vagrant setup is ok - before the log-out everything is fine. I have port forwarding setup and everything.

The version are:

- ruby 2.0.0dev (2013-02-08 trunk 39161)
- Rails 4.0.0

Comment: Try to run "rails server -d" instead of "rails server &"

Comment: @Emyl Would you care to turn that into an answer so that I could accept it? :>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run `rails server -d` instead of `rails server &`

Answer (score 0):

I the interest of being complete I just want to say that running the server via `nohup` will also get the desired result, as in:

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
cd /vagrant
nohup rails server
```

But you should probably stick to the accepted answer as it's a more standard way.